# User Session already opened Issue Because Of this i cannot run tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-side-runner

**I have multiple test Suite contains multiple tests inside it. Please see the structure of my testsuite below.**
PracticeTestSuiteOne

- Test1
- Test2
- Test3
- Test4
- Test5
- Test6
  If i run PracticeTestSuiteOne in command line runner.It started with Test1 contains my application logging in and doing some tests and logging out and then going to Test2.In this case it is fine for me.

If i run PracticeTestSuiteOne in command line runner.It started with Test1 contains my application logging in and doing some tests and failed in somewhere then it is not going upto logoutTest. it is juming going to Test2.In this case i cannot test my next test case because my session already opened at previous Test1 .

In command line runner i want to learn all the tests in the PracticeTestSuiteOne.How to acheive this situation.Because of test1 fails i cannot run remaining test in the PracticeTestSuiteOne.

I want to generate report because of this tests i m running from command line runner but this issue occured.Because of session exists i cannot test all the tests.I cannot able to generate.

I want to generate report for the tests using command line runner or any other way for all the tests